# Redirection using Axios and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a little problem with Axios and I don't know how to redirect after a signup or a login.

Here is my code:

```
axios.post("/api/user/signup", { data })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      console.log("REDIRECTION avec status => ", res.status);
      // how to redirect here
      <Redirect to = {{ pathname: "/home" }} />
    }
```

The flow reaches the `console.log` call but I can't find how to redirect after it in React.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on your usage of the `Redirect` component, I assume you are using React Router as the routing-logic library.

React Router (v4) handles routing at rendering time.

This means that redirection will happen when the `Redirect` component is rendered.

One way to control this is by leveraging the state.

In React, changing the state causes a re-rerender.

Here's one approach:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSignedUp: false // <-- initialize the signup state as false
    }
  }

  signup() {
    return axios.post("/api/user/signup", { data })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.setState({ isSignedUp: true }); // after signing up, set the state to true. This will trigger a re-render
        }
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    if (this.state.isSignedUp) {
      // redirect to home if signed up
      return <Redirect to = {{ pathname: "/home" }} />;
    }

    // ... rest of rendering code    
  }
```

Comment: hello, yes sure, perfect i will try

Comment: axios.post must be in a function ? or it can be in the component like you did

Comment: In a function. Where do you have it now? Just leave it at the same place

Comment: I have in in my function postData which is called with onChange on my form

Comment: Sure, there's no need to change that.

Comment: @jim2k glad to help mate :)